# convert mysql to xml and encode to json

Tags: mysql, json

help me please, i have problem with my code, dan saya pusing sekali tolong bantu saya

view my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");


// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: You definitely should provide some additional information on what you're trying to achieve to your question